# D3 update values to a new dataset on mouse click

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

All, I am having difficulty updating the values of some circles I have drawn with D3. Entire code is below.

You will see that there are 3 values in dataset1 and 4 values in dataset2.

All I simply want to do is update the circles on a mouse click of a button from dataset1 to dataset2.

However when I run this code, only the first three values of dataset2 are updated, the fourth value is missing. this must be something to do with the fact that dataset1 only have 3 values and therefore only updating the first 3 values in dataset2.

Appreciate a response which tells me exactly what I need to do not just something like, do update or something. I have searched a lot but most responses are vague.

Very grateful for your help.

```
    <html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="d3/d3.js"> </script>
    <title>update data</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
 <p id = "h">test</p>   
 <button onclick="fader()">Click me</button> 
<script>    



var dataset1 = [30,90,150];
 var dataset2 = [5,30,100,79];

 d3.selectAll("#h") 
.append("svg")
.attr("width",200)
.attr("height",200)

.selectAll("circle")
.attr("id","mastercircle")        
.append("svg")
.data(dataset1)
.enter()
.append("circle")
.attr("id","mycircle")      
.attr("cy", 90)
.attr("cx", String)
.attr("r", Math.sqrt)
.attr("fill","green")


 .style("opacity", 1)
 .transition().duration(600) 
 .style("opacity", 0.5)    
    ;

   function fader() {


      d3.selectAll("#mycircle")

        .data(dataset2) 

    .attr("cy", 90)
    .attr("cx", String)
    .attr("r", Math.sqrt)
    .attr("fill","red")
    .style("opacity", 1)
    .transition().duration(1000)
     .style("opacity", 0.5)     

    ;

    };


   </script>


</body>
 </html>
```

See code after fully expanding the FIDDLE code. It now adds the new data but doesn't remove the old data. Grateful if you can tell me where I need to exit and remove?

Just trying to learn exactly what is going on without using variables to understand what D3 is actually doing.

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="d3/d3.js"> </script>
        <title>Delete</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
     <p id = "h">test</p>   
       <button id = "update">Click me</button> 
<script>    



var dataset1 = [30, 90, 150];
var dataset2 = [5, 30, 100, 79];

 d3.select("#h") //p must be loaded for this to work i.e. above the code
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width",200)
    .attr("height",200)

    .selectAll("circle")
    .data(dataset1)

 //sel above

    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("class","circles")


    .attr("cy", 90)
    .attr("cx", String)
    .attr("r", Math.sqrt)
    .attr("fill","green")    
    .style("opacity", 1)
    .transition().duration(600)
    .style("opacity", 0.5)    
    ;

function fader() {


d3.select("#h") 

.append("svg")
    .attr("width",200)
    .attr("height",200)
    //.selectAll("circle")
    //.data(dataset1)
    .selectAll(".circles")  
    .data(dataset2)



      .enter() // enter selection
      .append("circle")
        .attr("class", "circles")

      //update selection
        .transition().duration(1000)
        .attr("cy", 90) 
        .attr("cx", String)
        .attr("r", Math.sqrt)
        .attr("fill", "red")
        .style("opacity", 1)     
        .style("opacity", 0.5)    ;

};

d3.select("#update").on("click", fader);



</script>


    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are lots of resources on understanding the enter/update/exit pattern, and one of the most popular is [Thinking with Joins](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/join/) by the creator of D3.

I have applied this important pattern to your code and placed it in this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Zzaw7/). You can look at the code (with key comments) and compare to the explanations in Mike's post.

```
sel 
    .enter() // enter selection
    .append("circle")
    .attr("class", "circles");

sel //update selection
    .attr("cy", 90)
    .attr("cx", String)
    ...
```

NOTE: one commonly overlooked aspect is the importance of giving a specific class to the elements you draw so that you can refer to them by this class when you want to update them or handle them in any other way (class `circles` in the code). I also moved the second transition to an earlier point so that you can clearly see the new circle being added to the group, and in the correct position.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this, after reading it about 5 times on the FIDDLE I think I understand what is going on. I had not ever come across a proper example of exit and remove. One thing I don't understand is, why you exit a selection before applying it? i.e. Sel.exit().remove()...and then you proceed to enter()??. I will read your link. and your FIDDLE example is very clear, although I don't understand the remove and exit very well. Cheers.

Comment: You could just as well place the exit selection AFTER the enter/update...it does not really matter...these are the elements which D3 have slated/allocated for removal and do not participate in the enter/update selections. In your example, the exit selection is not really needed since you are not removing any elements...but I always use it since it does not hurt and it will be there when you need it. It forms a good habit :)

Comment: Thanks, just one last thing, what does d3.select("#update").on("click", fader); actually do?I know it's referencing the fader function. My original button was <button onclick="fader()">Click me</button>. I guess it's not referencing the D3 in any way?

Comment: It selects the button and adds an onclick event listener to it, your function `fader()`. It is just another way of doing the same thing you were doing before but using D3.

Comment: Okay I have gone through the code and can see what is going on. there is just one thing I don't understand. what does the code at the start of the function fader, expand out into: sel = svg.selectAll(".circles")? what is all the code it covers? I am trying to expand out all your code into a long D3 statement so that I can understand what each bit is doing. many thanks. See my amended code above - which still doesn't quite work probably because i am not exiting ?